# How to properly implement MapQuest's API in Android Studio 3.3

Tags: java, android, gradle, mapquest, android-studio-3.3

I have followed what seems to be broken documentation on implementing MapQuest's API for Android to have access in using map functions.

I keep getting this error code in the gradle build process:

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.mapquest:mapping-android-sdk:2.0.10.

I also get similar results when requesting

`com.mapquest:searchahead:1.3.0`

`com.mapquest:navigation:3.4.0`

What is the correct notation for implementing the current builds for MapQuest's API's?

Comment: Please post your gradle file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an Artifactory issue over the weekend that has been resolved. It should be working now.